# How to get existing php/python version number from node.js app

Tags: php, node.js

I was trying to create a command line node.js app using commander module. This app would download few files based on php version installed in my machine. Can someone help me with sample of how to get the php version number from node.js app

I tried something as below but dint worked, i would replace npm -v with php -v later

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;    
exec('npm -v', function(err, data) {  
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data.toString());                       
});
```

Error:

{ [Error: spawn npm -v ENOENT]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm -v',
  path: 'npm -v',
  cmd: 'npm -v' }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`child_process.exec()` works fine for me:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('php -r "echo phpversion();"', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.dir(stdout.toString());
});

// Outputs:
// '5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1'
```

For python you can do something like this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version())"',
     function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.dir(stdout.toString());
});

// Outputs:
// '2.7.10'
```